# How to make UITableViewRowAction Completely Transparent in UitableView in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I want to make UITableViewRowAction transparent and my background view should be visible on swipe my UITableViewCell left in Objective-C. I've cleared all background colors but still getting a light gray color in the background.

Here is my Code:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
    
    
    
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *MyCustomTableView;
    @property (nonatomic, strong)NSArray *MyTableViewData;
    @property (nonatomic, strong)UIImage *MyAppIconImage;
    @end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyTableViewCell.h"

static NSString *myCellID = @"myCellIdentifier";
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize MyCustomTableView, MyTableViewData, MyAppIconImage;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SampleBg"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];

    self.MyTableViewData = @[@{@"Title" : @"My TableView Title 1", @"Description" : @"My TableView Description 1"}, @{@"Title" : @"My TableView Title 2", @"Description" : @"My TableView Description 2"}, @{@"Title" : @"My TableView Title 3", @"Description" : @"My TableView Description 3"}, @{@"Title" : @"My TableView Title 4", @"Description" : @"My TableView Description 4"}, @{@"Title" : @"My TableView Title 5", @"Description" : @"My TableView Description 5"}, @{@"Title" : @"My TableView Title 6", @"Description" : @"My TableView Description 6"}, @{@"Title" : @"My TableView Title 7", @"Description" : @"My TableView Description 7"}, @{@"Title" : @"My TableView Title 8", @"Description" : @"My TableView Description 8"}];
    
    
    
UIImage *AppIconAsset = [UIImage imageNamed: [[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary[@"CFBundleIcons"][@"CFBundlePrimaryIcon"][@"CFBundleIconFiles"] lastObject]];
    self.MyAppIconImage = [self ResizeImage: AppIconAsset scaledToSize: CGSizeMake(36, 36)];
    
    self.MyCustomTableView = [UITableView new];
    self.MyCustomTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview: self.MyCustomTableView];
    self.MyCustomTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.MyCustomTableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[MyCustomTableView]|" options: 0 metrics: nil views: @{@"MyCustomTableView" : self.MyCustomTableView}]];
    
    [self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[MyCustomTableView]|" options: 0 metrics: nil views: @{@"MyCustomTableView" : self.MyCustomTableView}]];
    MyCustomTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    
    [self.MyCustomTableView registerClass: [MyTableViewCell class].self forCellReuseIdentifier: myCellID];
    self.MyCustomTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0);
    self.MyCustomTableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;
    self.MyCustomTableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
    [self.MyCustomTableView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.MyCustomTableView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.MyCustomTableView setContentOffset: self.MyCustomTableView.contentOffset animated: NO];
    self.MyCustomTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
    self.MyCustomTableView.backgroundView = nil;
   // self.MyCustomTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    [self.MyCustomTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    self.MyCustomTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
    [self.MyCustomTableView.inputAccessoryView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    self.MyCustomTableView.opaque = NO;
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return  1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return  [self.MyTableViewData count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    MyTableViewCell *myCell = (MyTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: myCellID forIndexPath: indexPath];
    if (myCell == nil) {
        myCell = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier: myCellID];
    }
    
    myCell.MyCellImageView = [UIImageView new];
    myCell.MyCellImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [myCell.contentView addSubview: myCell.MyCellImageView];
    [myCell.contentView addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"H:|-12-[MyCellImageView(34)]" options: 0 metrics: nil views: @{@"MyCellImageView": myCell.MyCellImageView}]];
    [myCell.contentView addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:|-5-[MyCellImageView(34)]" options: 0 metrics: nil views: @{@"MyCellImageView": myCell.MyCellImageView}]];
    
   
    
    
    myCell.MyCellImageView.image = self.MyAppIconImage;
    myCell.MyCellImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    myCell.MyCellImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    myCell.MyCellImageView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    myCell.MyCellImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    myCell.MyCellImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 17;
    
    
    myCell.MyCellTitleLabel = [UILabel new];
    myCell.MyCellDescriptionLabel = [UILabel new];
    myCell.MyCellTitleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    myCell.MyCellDescriptionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    
    [myCell.contentView addSubview: myCell.MyCellTitleLabel];
    [myCell.contentView addSubview: myCell.MyCellDescriptionLabel];
    
    [myCell.contentView addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"H:[MyCellImageView]-10-[MyCellTitleLabel]-10-|" options: 0 metrics: nil views: @{@"MyCellTitleLabel" : myCell.MyCellTitleLabel, @"MyCellImageView": myCell.MyCellImageView}]];
    [myCell.contentView addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"H:[MyCellImageView]-10-[MyCellDescriptionLabel]-10-|" options: 0 metrics: nil views: @{@"MyCellDescriptionLabel" : myCell.MyCellDescriptionLabel, @"MyCellImageView": myCell.MyCellImageView}]];
    [myCell.contentView addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:|-10-[MyCellTitleLabel]" options: 0 metrics: nil views: @{@"MyCellTitleLabel" : myCell.MyCellTitleLabel}]];
    
    [myCell.contentView addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:[MyCellTitleLabel]-(5)-[MyCellDescriptionLabel]-10-|" options: 0 metrics: nil views: @{@"MyCellTitleLabel" : myCell.MyCellTitleLabel, @"MyCellDescriptionLabel" : myCell.MyCellDescriptionLabel}]];
    
    
     myCell.MyCellTitleLabel.text = [[self.MyTableViewData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey: @"Title"];
    
    myCell.MyCellDescriptionLabel.text = [[self.MyTableViewData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey: @"Description"];
    myCell.MyCellDescriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    myCell.MyCellDescriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    
    myCell.MyCellDescriptionLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
    myCell.MyCellDescriptionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    
    myCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    myCell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    myCell.backgroundView.opaque = NO;
    myCell.backgroundView = nil;
    myCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return myCell;
}



- (NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell *myCell = [MyCustomTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    [myCell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    UITableViewRowAction *rowAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title: @"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction * _Nonnull action, NSIndexPath * _Nonnull indexPath) {
        
        NSLog(@"rowAction Performed !!");
    }];
    rowAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return @[rowAction];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //  [self.objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}


-(UIImage*)ResizeImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

**MyTableViewCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *MyCellTitleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong)UILabel *MyCellDescriptionLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong)UIImageView *MyCellImageView;

@end
```

**MyTableViewCell.m**

```
#import "MyTableViewCell.h"

@implementation MyTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

-(id)initWithStyle: (UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier: (NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        
        
        //    self.nvFullScrnPlayerDelegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    
    for(UIView *subview in [self.contentView subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
//    for (UIView *subview in  self.subviews) {
//        for (UIView *subview2 in subview.subviews) {
//
////NSRange range = ;
//            if ([(NSString *)subview2 rangeOfString:@"UITableViewCellActionButton"].location != NSNotFound) {
//                NSLog(@"1234567890");
//            }
////            if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
////                for (UIView *view in  subview2.subviews) {
////
////NSRange newRange = [(NSString *)view rangeOfString: @"UIButtonLabel"];
//////     if (String(view).rangeOfString("UIButtonLabel") != nil) {
////if (newRange.location != NSNotFound) {
////    UILabel *Textlabel = (UILabel *)view;
////    if (Textlabel == (UILabel *) view) {
////        Textlabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
////    }
////                    }
////                }
////            }
//
//        }
//    }      

}
@end
```

And here is my Result:

[image]

**On Swiping second time on the same tableview cell I'm getting the expected result but not in the first time of swiping.**

Can anybody help me to resolvr it ?

Comment: Try this way In editActionsForRowAtIndexPath
    MyTableViewCell *myCell = (MyTableViewCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];   and rowAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 For reference:- http://qaru.site/questions/94631/custom-edit-view-in-uitableviewcell-while-swipe-left-objective-c-or-swift

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath add tag for each cell like  myCell.tag = indexPath.row;

Comment: Same the gray background not removed on swipe. I want to remove the light gray background permanently while swipe cell to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you!

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
{  
    UITableViewRowAction *callAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {  

        NSLog(@"View Action fired");  
    }];  
    callAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  

    return @[callAction];  
}
```

Comment: Try this @MohammadAshrafAli and Let me know !

Comment: As I've tested again this is working fine in iOS 10 but the gray background is coming in iOS 11 or above device. And iPhoneX Simulator screenshot is attached.

Answer (score 0):

If you set clear color means its showing light gray color.Instead of clear color you can set SampleBg image.From image you can get same tableview background color Try below code.It will work

```
- (NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewRowAction *rowAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction * _Nonnull action, NSIndexPath * _Nonnull indexPath) {

        NSLog(@"rowAction Performed !!");
    }];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SampleBg"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    rowAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
    return @[rowAction];
}
```

Comment: Hi Rajesh it's drawing an image of the main view from its top left corner so the image looks like a different image because of the gradient color in the main image